# Ionic 3 Google maps - map doesn't show on android

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework

i'm trying to use geolocation and google maps with ionic 3, the app is working fine in the browser:

[image]

but for some reason, when i build the apk is not showing the map on my phone

[image]

this the geolocation .ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Geolocation, Geoposition } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';

declare var google;

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-geo',
  templateUrl: 'geo.html',
})
export class GeoPage {
  map: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public geo: Geolocation) { }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.getPosition();
  }

  getPosition():any{
    this.geo.getCurrentPosition().then(resp => {

      this.loadMap(resp);

    }).catch((error) =>{
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
  loadMap(position: Geoposition){

let latitud = position.coords.latitude;
let longitud = position.coords.longitude;
console.log(latitud, longitud);

let mapEle: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('map');

let myLatLng = {lat: latitud, lng: longitud};

this.map = new google.maps.Map(mapEle, {
  center: myLatLng,
  zoom: 12
});



google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(this.map, 'idle', () => {
  let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: this.map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });
  mapEle.classList.add('show-map');
    });

  }



}
```

i don't know what's wrong, thanks in advice

[image]

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: no, it's even showing latitud and longitud, there's no error, that's the thing, it's not working on my phone,but  it is on the browser

Comment: I think your map div isnt loaded yet.. use ViewChild instead of document.getElement

Comment: can you console log `mapEle`?

Comment: yes, it shows a really big div, with the id map, i'll add the screenshot to the original post

Comment: You are setting height of map in % or in px?

Comment: Paresh, this particular issue is "solved", now i'm facing another problem, it does work on android but you MUST turn on the gps before opening the app or it won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you call `loadMap(resp)` only after successfully getting geolocation.

If the geolocation request fails (due to permissions) then the app will not load.

You need to load the map then set the center:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.loadmap()
    this.getPosition();
}

getPosition(): any {
    this.geo.getCurrentPosition().then(resp => {
        this.setCenter(resp);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    })
}

loadMap() {
    let mapEle: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('map');
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(mapEle, {
        center: myLatLng,
        zoom: 12
    });
}

setCenter(position: Geoposition) {
    let myLatLng = { lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude };
    this.map.setCenter(myLatLng);

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(this.map, 'idle', () => {
        let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: this.map,
            title: 'Hello World!'
        });
        mapEle.classList.add('show-map');
    });
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can call `loadMap()` in the `.catch()` of the geolocation promise, and the load the map there without coords.

```
getPosition(): any {
    this.geo.getCurrentPosition().then(resp => {
        this.loadMap(resp);
    }).catch((error) => {
        // Load the map even if we fail
        this.loadMapFallback();
        console.log(error);
    });
}

/*
 ... old load map function
 */

loadMapFallback() {
    let mapEle: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('map');

    this.map = new google.maps.Map(mapEle, {
        zoom: 12
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks man, this issue has been fixed, but i'll give you accepted answer(i don't know how to close the topic)

Comment: No problem. Typically if your issue is solved you would post the answer yourself and accept it so future readers can get the answer.